# Hyper-V Integration Services when hosting a Win2k8 SP2 VM on a Win2k8 RTM Hyper-V Host

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

Now that Win2k8 with SP2 ISO's are available for download, I'm installing a new Win2k8 Std SP2 VM on my Win2k8 RTM Hyper-V host machine.

If I "Insert Integration Services Disk" on the new SP2 VM from my non-SP2 host machine, would I be introducing old "Integration Services" drivers on the SP2 VM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WS08 SP2 comes with the latest Integration Components already installed. If you were to try to "insert Integration Services disk", it should detect that the ICs are already installed and prompt you for confirmation.

Long story short... you're good.  No need to do anything :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe IS is going to be installed on your 2008 guest at all, prior to hyper V recognizing it.  The only time I could imagine it being a problem is if you have SP1 HV host and a SP2 HV host moving that VM back and forth.

One way to verify would be to compare your IS version numbers:

- Open device manager on the VM
- Pull up the property sheet for a vmBus device (e.g. Virtual Machine Bus)
- In the Driver tab, check the last set of digits - such as 18016